# Python - Most efficient way to sort array for searching in it

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, search, data-structures

I have a very large numpy array that looks like this (first 5 entries):

```
[[ 1.    0.01  0.02  0.6   0.01  0.5   0.01  0.5   0.5   0.5 ]
 [ 0.5   0.01  0.01  0.6   0.01  0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.6 ]
 [ 0.6   0.01  0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.7   0.01  0.01  0.  ]
 [ 0.01  0.5   0.8   0.02  0.02  0.81  0.01  0.77  0.02  0.01]
 [ 0.5   0.02  0.5   0.    0.5   0.5   0.01  0.6   0.01  0.  ]]
```

I **search this array** for specific sequences that are also 10 values long.
So I store the incoming sequences after no special rule, just 0 1 2 3 ... and the same I search this array. This is my **search method (silo_arrays[][] is the array above, array_pattern[] is a 1D numpy 10 values long array for which I search the silo_arrays)**:

```
   new_pattern=True
   for z in range(0, self.silo_arrays_c):
    eq_rate = 0
    for y in range(0, self.length):
        if(self.silo_arrays[z][y] != array_pattern[y]):
            break
        else:
            eq_rate += 1

    if(eq_rate == self.length):
     new_pattern = False
     break
```

This takes about 0.006257s if the silo_arrays is something like 1585 entries long. Has anyone ideas on how to **accelerate this search process** by some kind of **sorting** or **structural changes**?
Thank you for your support :)

Comment: `np.where((silo_arrays==array_pattern).all(1))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to data-optimization you're often dealing with **trade-offs** rather than an overall acceleration.

So before using the following solution, make sure that you understand the limitations that come with it, namely an increased write-time.

One popular algorithm would be to implement a Binary Search. In case you're not familiar with the concept:

Given an ordered numerical list *L*, and a numerical *v*, you have to check if `v in L`. You can do so, by splitting the list in half and then comparing the middle value of these two intervals against your value *v*. Assuming ascending order you will choose an interval *I* based on the following rules: `if v < L[middleindex]: I = lower_half else I = upper_half` You then continue your search by repeating. This way you reduce your search space to a minimum.

In order to use Binary Search in your project, you'd need to sort your arrays when inserting them in the array. The values to compare against would be your arrays elements in descending order. That way you will likely increase the search speed.

The upsides of using Binary Search is that in both scenarios (worst and best case) it performs equally, namely *O(log n)*.  That makes it quite reliable.

Excuse formatting, I'm on mobile.